# How to trigger saving a field in another table when data in one table is saved in the Django Admin inerface?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, database, django-models

These are my models.

```py
class User(models.Model):
    USER_TYPES = (
        ('P', 'Professor'),
        ('S', 'Student')
    )

    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=USER_TYPES)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...


class StudentDetail(models.Model):
    student = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    ...


class ProfessorDetail(models.Model):
    professor = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

I am using the `DjangoAdmin` interface to populate these tables. Is there a way to trigger a request to save data in another table when data in one table is saved?

I want to be automatically redirected to entering data for either `StudentDetail` or `ProfessorDetail` based on the value that is saved in the `User` table.

I want this to happen in the Django admin interface. Otherwise, this would be pretty simple.

Comment: Any reasons not to use a post_save signal?

Comment: @DanieleBernardini I didn't know about that. Thanks! I'll look into it.